# How to fix that warnings in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

flutter showing these warnings:

```
/C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
                               ^

Note: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.
```

```
/////////////////////
compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.examples"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for the library to be updated. There are several open issues regarding this one on GitHub. https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/issues/239

Comment: Hi, this think for only flutter_datetime_picker ?  or all warnings?